# Why cant I add var in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to run a simple program to teach my friend to code:

```
var name = prompt("Whats your name"); 
if name = "Jason" {alert ("your name is Jason");
```

but for some reason it just wont let me ad the variable "name". What should I do?

Comment: Which language is this? javascript?

Comment: yes, pure it is pure JS

Comment: You haven't yet learnt the very basics of JavaScript yourself. You should be trying to learn it with your friend instead of trying to teach them. `if ( name === "Jason" ) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need

```
if (name === "Jason") { /*Do something */}
```

Rather than the single equals. Double/triple equals compares whereas single equals sets.

Comment: In Javascript we should almost always use triple equal signs.

Comment: I do agree, thanks for pointing that out I have edited my answer @chevybow